# Saber el valor máximo y mínimo de un producto dentro de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Hola queridos amigos del foro, una vez mas me hago presente por acá ya que ando con problemas al realizar una consulta mysql.

Tengo una tabla productos que cuenta con 2 campos que son (precio_general y precio_oferta) si el precio oferta esta establecido (distinto de 0) entonces el precio para ese producto sera el precio de oferta que lo devuelve en un campo llamado precio.

Consulta mysql:

```
SELECT id_producto, 
       nombre, 
       descripcion, 
       img, 
       IF(precio_oferta != 0, precio_oferta, precio_general) as precio 
FROM productos
```

Lo que necesito realizar, es poder seleccionar de esa tabla el valor del producto mas caro y del mas barato, considerando que puede tener el precio oferta establecido.

Como lo harían? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he resuelto utilizando tu propia consulta como subquery:

```
SELECT ROUND(MAX(precio),2) maximo,
  ROUND(MIN(precio),2) minimo
  FROM (
    SELECT id_producto, 
           nombre, 
           descripcion, 
           img,
           IF(precio_oferta != 0, precio_oferta, precio_general) as precio
    FROM productos
  ) c1;
```

A partir de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id_producto int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(63),
  descripcion text,
  img blob,
  precio_oferta float,
  precio_general float
  );
INSERT INTO productos (nombre, precio_oferta, precio_general) VALUES
  ('Detergente',9.99,10.99),
  ('Jabón',1.99,2.99),
  ('Pan',0,.69),
  ('Chicle',0.05,0.1);
```

Obtengo este resultado:

> ```
> =======================
> |    maximo|    minimo|
> =======================
> |      9,99|      0,05|
> -----------------------
> ```

Espero que te resulte útil.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda David!